# "Более(,) чем на" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Нужно было решить тесты по математике не более(,) чем на 50%.*

Answer (score 1):

Цитирую [Грамоту](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68):

> **(НЕ) БОЛЕЕ / БОЛЬШЕ, ЧЕМ,** *в составе сравнительного оборота*
>
> <...>
>
> Однако при отсутствии сравниваемых понятий слова «(не) более / больше чем» образуют с последующими словами неразложимое сочетание (единый член предложения), не требующее постановки знаков препинания. Как правило, в этом случае после слов «(не) более / больше чем» следует количественно-именное сочетание (счетный оборот) или название единицы измерения (час, грамм, километр и т. п.).

А вообще, вашу фразу я бы переформулировал так:

*Чтобы пройти тесты по математике, достаточно было решить их на 50%.*